# Rephrasing of "a person with this habit/with a habit of"

Tags: word-usage, phrases

Is it grammatically and lexically correct to call a person with a particular habit "a habit holder" or "a habit carrier" for short?

Comment: It's *grammatical* but it's not at all natural.

Comment: Technically, yes.

Comment: Could you please suggest a more natural wording to me?

Comment: Are you talking about people who have *any* habit (as opposed to people with no habits at all), or people who have *one specific* habit? There's no real term for the former, since everyone has habits, but for the latter there are a variety of options depending on the exact habit. What kind of context would this term be used in?

Comment: A habitual (enter the habit).

Comment: @Alan T. I mean any person with a specific habit, say, smoking. If the context's clear, and It's not necessary to mention smoking itself each time while speaking about it, what speech pattern can I use then?

Comment: @AlexeyPlatonov In that case I don't see any particular reason not to just say "smokers". Similar logic applies with other habits, the simplest option is to use the habit plus [-er](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-er#Suffix) - nail-biters, nose-pickers, etc.

Comment: I just want to avoid repeating the same words and make my speech more varied.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, its actually hard to come up with something to describe a person with "any" habit.

I don't know what you are trying to convey by 'habit' here. A habit of smoking, taking drugs, etc? A habit of interrupting others while they are speaking?

Well, you can give these a try:

- **addict** (might be a bit extreme but may work for a habit of smoking, doing drugs, watching stuff, etc)
- **fanatic** (according to Collins: If you say that someone is a fanatic, you mean that they are very enthusiastic about a particular activity, sport, or way of life.)
- **devotee** (google: a person who is very interested in and enthusiastic about someone or something.)
- **enthusiast** (google: a person who is highly interested in a particular activity or subject)
- **proclivity** (google: a tendency to choose or do something regularly; an inclination or predisposition toward a particular thing.)
- **inveterate** (google: having a particular habit, activity, or interest that is long-established and unlikely to change. "he was an inveterate gambler")
- **congenital** (google: (of a person) having a particular trait from birth or by firmly established habit. "a congenital liar")

Comment: Thank you. But I'm asking about any person with **a paticular** (not **any**) habit. It may be smoking or, for instance, talking to yourself out loud. What can I say instead of "people with a habit of talking to themselves out loud" if I want to avoid repeating the full name of the habit? Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: @AlexeyPlatonov soliloquist/soliloquize/soliloquy, introspection/introspective/introspect. I think these come close, but are not exact.

Comment: Thanks. As I can see, there is no natural-sounding universal substitution like "a habit holder/carrier" which fits any case.